# Can I return to my home country (NZ) with a day left on my passport?

Tags: passports, new-zealand-citizens

My NZ passport is due to expire 2 days after I return from living in Mexico for years. Is this going to cause me any problems?

Would it be an issue for Mexican immigration?

Comment: Since you are a NZ citizen, NZ has to let you go home. Mexico shouldn't have an issue because they'll have to deport you if you stayed longer than you were allowed.

Comment: NZ would likely let you in even with an expired passport, but the airline would likely not let you board.

Answer (score 3):

Your New Zealand passport needs to be valid on arrival only. It does not need any period of validity beyond that.

```
Information as of  04MAY17 / 0557 UTC
National New Zealand (NZ)       /Embarkation Mexico (MX)
Destination New Zealand (NZ)
New Zealand (NZ)

Passport required.
- Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to
nationals of New Zealand must be valid on arrival.

VISA NOT REQUIRED.
```

The Mexicans are only interested in ensuring you have the correct  paperwork to exit: temporary visitors get part 2 of their entry form stapled to their passport, which must be returned on exit, but I am not sure what the procedure is for long term residents. They won't worry about your passport being close to expiry.